# Selenium Chrome driver Print to PDF, can't change the paper size with MediaSize's microns

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to save web page design into pdf file.
I've searched the solution and they all saying about dealing `MediaSize`.

I want to save it as "legal" size, and it is 355600 height microns, and 215900 width microns.
So this is the code I used:

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

settings = {
    "recentDestinations": [{
        "id": "Save as PDF",
        "origin": "local",
        "account": ""
    }],
    "selectedDestinationId": "Save as PDF",
    "version": 2,
    "mediaSize": {
        "height_microns": 355600,
        "width_microns": 215900,
        "name": "NA_legal",
        "custom_display_name": "legal"
    },
    "isCssBackgroundEnabled": True,
    "isHeaderFooterEnabled": True,
}


prefs = {'printing.print_preview_sticky_settings.appState' : json.dumps(settings)}

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--kiosk-printing')
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)

driver = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver.exe", options=chrome_options)
driver.get('page')
driver.execute_script('window.print();')
```

And I compared it with the pdf which I made by manual. It has different height(and maybe width as well).

I changed the `height_microns` and `width_microns` dramatically, and found out it isn't affected at all.

Did I miss something? Or was it deprecated somehow?
Thank you in advance!

Edit: I checked the spec and I think it somehow got recognized as unavailable value, and get `width_microns: 215900, height_microns: 279400`. But not sure why is that so... (https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/eadef3f685cd9e96e94fcb9645b6838b6d0907a8/chrome/browser/resources/print_preview/data/model.js)